# ABCD parameters

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks

I am trying to get the ABCD parameters of these circuit but I have no idea about how to solve the circuit. All I know is
V1=AV2+BI2
I1=CV2+DI2
But here no impedance is connected. If I short the output,V2=0 then what is B? Please help me out.

[image]

Comment: As you well know of as a poster of 14 previous such questions, the site is not a homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopaedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail. Learning is about learning to research and understand for yourself. This information is readily available on the internet.

Comment: Why is it looking like a homework to you? I have not asked to solve the problem...I asked any idea about how can it be solved..

Comment: Let's remove that objection, then. As you well know of as a poster of 14 previous such questions, the site is not an on-line technical encyclopaedia, copied out to you on demand, or discussion forum for personal step-by-step tutorial. People help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail. Learning is about learning to research and understand for yourself. This information is readily available on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, in matrix form, for a two port network we have these formulas: -

[image]

And that reduces to two formula: -

$$V_{IN} = A\cdot I_{IN} + B\cdot I_{OUT}$$

and

$$V_{OUT} = C\cdot I_{IN} + D\cdot I_{OUT}$$

So, it's just a case of figuring out how these two formulas match the circuit in your question and what the ABCD parameters are.

So, look at your formulas (a variant of the above) and figure out what A and B are first: -

$$V_1 = A\cdot V_2 + B\cdot I_2$$

One of those parameters is 0 and one of them is -1. That's all I can reasonably help you with given this site's rules about homework type questions that don't show any effort.